# Excel VBA Connection String for ODBC System DSN

Tags: odbc, tns

I am trying to create an Oracle connection string in Excel VBA.  After lots of research, I have a working connection string:

```
Set Oracle_conn = New ADODB.Connection
Oracle_conn.Open "ODBC; Driver='Oracle in instantclient_19_9'; Data Source='Data Mart'; UserID=" & ID & "; Password=" & Password & ";"
```

However, this only works when my ODBC Data Source is a **User** DSN.  When the ODBC Data Source is a **System** DSN, I end up with:
"[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

The reason I am using **System** DSN is because my code runs from a shared PC, so System DSN works for all users without each individual user needing to create a **User** DSN.

Any advice on how to tweak my code such that it will run with a **System** DSN would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit 1: System DSN connects successfully if I manually go to Data ribbon > Get Data > From Other Sources > From ODBC

Edit 2: I still haven't been able to figure out how to connect to a System DSN with VBA code.  Maybe it's a bug with the ODBC driver?  I realize this is a bit of an obscure question, but I'm still hopeful someone can help me connect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, I am not sure if this will work for Oracle, however for MSSQL I was having issues connecting to a System DSN. Basically I was over specifying elements that were already configured with **ODBC Data Sources**.

To get my System DSN all I needed was `conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & <DSN_NAME (string)> & ";"`

[Credit to the original poston Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29054012/VBA-Connect-to-SQL-DB-with-use-of-a-DSN.html)

To assist with administration and allowing it to be remotely pushed, I store the DSN name as a System Environment variable. In VBA I set a local variable to the DSN name with `DSN_NAME = Environ("ENV_DSN_NAME")`

Comment: Thank you lifedroid for your response. I had all but given up hope. I set up the consolidated string as you described, and created the System Environment variable as well. 

Unfortunately, I ended up with the same ORA-01017 error as described in the original post.

Very strange.  I even tried ChatGPT to try to generate some code, and it came up with code pretty similar to my original code above.  It led to the same ORA-01017 error.  My username and password are definitely correct, and I am able to connect successfully under the ODBC Test Connection window.